# MSSQL Query omitting specific row value?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following query to retrieve the customer sales report based on customer ID. It works, but how can I omit the customer name being duplicated?

```
select Cu.CustomerName, Cu.City, pd.pname, 
Cs.qty, Cs.totalAmount, Cs.payed, Cs.credit, Cs.CreditEndDate
from Customer Cu 
inner join CreditSales Cs on Cu.ID=Cs.CustomerID
left join Product pd on pd.pid=Cs.pid
where Cu.ID=6
order by Cu.CustomerName
```

The result is:

```
+--------+-------+---------------+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| Halima | Jimma | Mouse         |  1 | 345.00   | 345.00   | 0.00     | 2015-08-29 |
| Halima | Jimma | Mobile        | 10 | 92000.00 | 40000.00 | 52000.00 | 2015-08-23 |
| Halima | Jimma | Iphone        |  2 | 13800.00 | 6500.00  | 7300.00  | 2015-08-28 |
| Halima | Jimma | Tape Recorder | 10 | 5175.00  | 4000.00  | 1175.00  | 2015-10-30 |
+--------+-------+---------------+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

But I need like this:

```
+--------+-------+---------------+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| Halima | Jimma | Mouse         |  1 | 345.00   | 345.00   | 0.00     | 2015-08-29 |
|        | Jimma | Mobile        | 10 | 92000.00 | 40000.00 | 52000.00 | 2015-08-23 |
|        | Jimma | Iphone        |  2 | 13800.00 | 6500.00  | 7300.00  | 2015-08-28 |
|        | Jimma | Tape Recorder | 10 | 5175.00  | 4000.00  | 1175.00  | 2015-10-30 |
+--------+-------+---------------+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

That means the customer name should displayed only one instance.

Any help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: good comment thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Milen Pavlov response, you can try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [CustomerName] order by [CustomerName]) = 1 THEN [CustomerName] ELSE '' END
FROM Customer 
ORDER BY [CustomerName]
```

Comment: Based on your exemplar answer the problem is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This could do the job (I need you have to add an ordering in the `over()` clause):

```
select case when a.rn > 1 then '' else a.CustomerName end as CustomerName, a.City, a.pname, a.qty, a.totalAmount, a.payed, a.credit, a.CreditEndDate
from 
(
    select Cu.CustomerName, Cu.City, pd.pname, 
       Cs.qty, Cs.totalAmount, Cs.payed, Cs.credit, Cs.CreditEndDate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Cu.CustomerName order by  Cs.CreditEndDate) as rn
    from Customer Cu 
      inner join CreditSales Cs on Cu.ID=Cs.CustomerID
         left join Product pd on pd.pid=Cs.pid
    where Cu.ID=6       
) a 
order by a.CustomerName
```

Comment: nice to add row number and then skipping name having number > 1 :)

Comment: Good base, But it has an error:  'The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER" must have an ORDER BY clause.'

Comment: I'm very interested by your answer, how can I use Order by for "Row_Number" function.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I have seen it: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: ok, remove the last line `order by Cu.CustomerName` and place it outside the `a` table, will edit my answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

don't think it's a job for SQL but if you insists you can create two tables the first one with all the rows and columns and than delete the first row, and the other table with the first row and just make a left join and make the join on all the fields.